# javascript split('\n') and not ('\n\n')

Tags: javascript, split, vue.js

I am trying to make a filter that splits all `\n` and rejoins them as `\n\n`. Is there a way to bypass all `\n\n` combinations and only target the single `\n`? The issue now is that everytime i unfocus the input the filter fires and adds additional spaces to existing double spaces. 
working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oe7axeab/701/

```
        filters: {
        lyrics: {
            write(input) {
                var line = input,
                        bomb = line.split("\n"),
                        group = bomb.join("\n\n");

                return group;
            },
        },
        marked: marked
    }
```

Comment: try .replace("\n\n", 'FOOBARBLABLABLA'); then split single, and then .replace("FOOBARBLABLABLA", "\n\n") back

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oe7axeab/702/

Comment: do you want to replace odd \n to even ones i.e. in case of \n\n\n you want to convert that to \n\n\n\ or don't want to touch that

Comment: This works perfectly

Comment: You could first replace all \n\n with \n to "normalize" the newlines, then convert all \n to \n\n.

Comment: I think this will work: `.replace(/(\w)(\n)(?!\n)/g, function ($0, $i){return $0 == '\n' ? $i : '\n\n'})`

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to create a regex where in it will select only single instance of \n and convert that to \n\n

var str   = 'test \n test1 \n\n test2 \n test3 \n\n';

```
    **var regex = /([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)/g;**

    if (str.match(regex)) {
        str = str.replace(regex, "$1" + "\n\n" + "$2");
    }
```

Output : 'test \n\n test1 \n\n test2 \n\n test3 \n\n'